# Sub writing and string concatenation

Tags: perl

Good day,

For work I am suddenly required to know Perl, and though I have dabbled in those arts years ago, I seem to be completely lost. For a Haskell/Java programmer, all these unstructured typing can get on the nerves.

However, I wrote this `sub` that is supposed to take an array of single-line strings and concatenate them to a single, multi-lined strings. I had it Like so:

```
sub unlines {
    my ( @lines ) = @_;
    my $str = "";
    foreach $line ( @lines ) {
        $str = join $str, chomp($line), "\n";
    }
    return $str;
}
```

And then I wanted to test it, of course:

```
print unlines(("GET / http1.1", "Host: localhost", ""));
```

And the result of the thing is

```
000
```

And a lot of newlines. I have absolutely no idea why that is. Anyone can help me and explain, perhaps, how all these argument passing to subs in Perl works? It seems to be very interesting to work with things like `@_` and `shift`, but the typing... it's a nightmare.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Can we switch jobs? I keep suffering from const correctness and other assorted type rigidity P-I-T-A issues ever since having to work a lot on C++ after the p[leasure of doing exclusively Perl.

Comment: I just discovered `ref` for getting the type but... oh jeez, this is gonna be horrible. I'd prefer C++ any day over this. Heck, even C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your trouble lies in how chomp works; it doesn't return the chomped variable, it returns the number of characters removed and alters the variable in-place.

So chomp first and join later, like this...

```
C:\temp>cat test.pl
my @lines = ('abc','def');
chomp @lines;
print join "\n",@lines;

C:\temp>test.pl
abc
def
C:\temp>
```

And for completeness, here's how your unlines() could look

```
sub unlines {
    my @lines = @_;
    chomp @lines;    
    return join "\n", @lines;
}
```

Comment: Will `chomp @_` affect the arguments variable out of the sub's scope?

Comment: @Scán - yes it would.  I've modified the unlines() routine in my answer to introduce a new variable so the sub will work with string literals (which otherwise couldn't be chomped in the sub)